# What is the reason behind php-fpm crashing?

Tags: php, symfony

Something really strange happened, took me a while to figure what went wrong but then i was able to do it.

So i have an object

```
class Client implements \Serializable{

    ....
    protected $name;
    protected $email;
    /**
    * @var string|null
    *
    */
    protected $color;
    ....

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->name
        ]);
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->name
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

at some point i wanted to store this object in the session (using symfony just as a notice) so after storing it obviously i wasnt able to retrieve the color from the `$session->$client->getColor()` so i just added it to the serialize/unserialize methods like this

```
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->name,
            $this->color
        ]);
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->name,
            $this->color
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

refreshing the page crashed the php-fpm and it wont relaunch the app till i remove the color from the methods. now i tried to logout re add the color to serialize/unserialize functions and sunddenly php-fpm didnt crash again!!
What caused this behavior? is it because the session was never reset? and if yes what exactly happened in there?

## EDIT

There is no error neither the php-fpm is crashing after i did log out, add the code then login again. the php-fpm error log was empty (idk why) and the piece of code which was causing the crash is exactly the following

```
$client = $this->get('session')->get('client');
$client->getColor();
```

and the client was set in session directly after loging

```
$clients = $user->getClients();
$this->get('session')->set('client',$clients->first());
```

here is the client from 'var_dump($client);' looked like before adding color to serialize and after

before

```
object(\Model\Client)#226 (16) { ["id":protected]=> int(36) ["name":protected]=> string(9) "testcolor" ["email":protected]=> string(22) ["color":protected]=> NULL .... }
```

after

```
object(\Model\Client)#226 (16) { ["id":protected]=> int(36) ["name":protected]=> string(9) "testcolor" ["email":protected]=> string(22) ["color":protected]=> string(9) #000fff .... }
```

you can see the difference in the color field.

for the last time :) the error only happened while i was logged in and changed the serialize function, otherwise i wont be able to get the color from the client object since its not being serialized in the session so it will be NULL.

Comment: `php-fpm` has a setting for error log file. Find the error log and check what it says. Also, you haven't posted **what** exactly `$this->color` contains, so - how can anyone help you? Personally, I wouldn't use `serialize`, I'd encode /decide it to / from JSON.

Comment: @N.B. i updated the questin, basically all of them are simply strings. as i said it was fixed so i dont really need help to fix the issue i am just concerned to know what exactly happened. the log error might be something will check it as well

Comment: Why don't you add your answer and mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Emil  because i still dont know what happened, the fix already in the question, logout -> do your changes to the session -> login